# CloseableHttpClient.execute freezes once every few weeks despite timeouts

Tags: java-8, apache-httpclient-4.x

We have a groovy singleton that uses PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(httpclient:4.3.6) with a pool size of 200 to handle very high concurrent connections to a search service and processes the xml response.

Despite having specified timeouts, it freezes about once a month but runs perfectly fine the rest of the time.

The groovy singleton below. The method retrieveInputFromURL seems to block on client.execute(get);

```
@Singleton(strict=false)
class StreamManagerUtil {
   // Instantiate once and cache for lifetime of Signleton class

   private static PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();

   private static CloseableHttpClient client;

   private static final IdleConnectionMonitorThread staleMonitor = new IdleConnectionMonitorThread(connManager);

   private int warningLimit;
   private int readTimeout;
   private int connectionTimeout;
   private int connectionFetchTimeout;

   private int poolSize;
   private int routeSize;

   PropertyManager propertyManager  = PropertyManagerFactory.getInstance().getPropertyManager("sebe.properties")

   StreamManagerUtil() {
      // Initialize all instance variables in singleton from properties file

      readTimeout = 6
      connectionTimeout = 6
      connectionFetchTimeout =6

      // Pooling
      poolSize = 200
      routeSize = 50

      // Connection pool size and number of routes to cache
      connManager.setMaxTotal(poolSize);
      connManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(routeSize);

      // ConnectTimeout : time to establish connection with GSA
      // ConnectionRequestTimeout : time to get connection from pool
      // SocketTimeout : waiting for packets form GSA

      RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
      .setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout * 1000)
      .setConnectionRequestTimeout(connectionFetchTimeout * 1000)
      .setSocketTimeout(readTimeout * 1000).build();

      // Keep alive for 5 seconds if server does not have keep alive header
      ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy myStrategy = new ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy() {
         @Override
         public long getKeepAliveDuration(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {
            HeaderElementIterator it = new BasicHeaderElementIterator
               (response.headerIterator(HTTP.CONN_KEEP_ALIVE));
            while (it.hasNext()) {
               HeaderElement he = it.nextElement();
               String param = he.getName();
               String value = he.getValue();
               if (value != null && param.equalsIgnoreCase
                  ("timeout")) {
                  return Long.parseLong(value) * 1000;
               }
            }
            return 5 * 1000;
         }
      };

      // Close all connection older than 5 seconds. Run as separate thread.
      staleMonitor.start();
      staleMonitor.join(1000);

      client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(config).setKeepAliveStrategy(myStrategy).setConnectionManager(connManager).build();
   }     

   private retrieveInputFromURL (String categoryUrl, String xForwFor, boolean isXml) throws Exception {

      URL url = new URL( categoryUrl );

      GPathResult searchResponse = null
      InputStream inputStream = null
      HttpResponse response;
      HttpGet get;
      try {
         long startTime = System.nanoTime();

         get = new HttpGet(categoryUrl);
         response =  client.execute(get);

         int resCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

         if (xForwFor != null) {
            get.setHeader("X-Forwarded-For", xForwFor)
         }

         if (resCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            if (isXml) {
               extractXmlString(response)
            } else {
               StringBuffer buffer = buildStringFromResponse(response)
               return buffer.toString();
            }
         }

      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         throw e;
      }
      finally {
         // Release connection back to pool
         if (response != null) {
            EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
         }
      }

   }

   private extractXmlString(HttpResponse response) {
      InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent()

      XmlSlurper slurper = new XmlSlurper()
      slurper.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false)
      slurper.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", false)
      slurper.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar", false)
      slurper.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false)

      return slurper.parse(inputStream)
   }

   private StringBuffer buildStringFromResponse(HttpResponse response) {
      StringBuffer buffer= new StringBuffer();
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
      String line = "";
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
         buffer.append(line);
         System.out.println(line);
      }
      return buffer
   }
```

```
public class IdleConnectionMonitorThread extends Thread {

    private final HttpClientConnectionManager connMgr;
    private volatile boolean shutdown;

    public IdleConnectionMonitorThread
      (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connMgr) {
        super();
        this.connMgr = connMgr;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!shutdown) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    wait(5000);
                    connMgr.closeExpiredConnections();
                    connMgr.closeIdleConnections(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // Ignore
        }
    }
    public void shutdown() {
        shutdown = true;
        synchronized (this) {
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

I also found found this in the log leading me to believe it happened on waiting for response data

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150) at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121) at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)

### Findings thus far:

- We are using java 1.8u25. There is an open issue on a similar scenario
  https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8075484
- HttpClient had a similar report https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1589 but this was fixed in 
  the 4.3.6 version we are using

### Questions

- Can this be a synchronisation issue? From my understanding even though the singleton is accessed by multiple threads, the only shared data is the cached CloseableHttpClient
- Is there anything else fundamentally wrong with this code,approach that may be causing this behaviour?

Comment: I'm assuming the missing semicolons are unintentional?

Comment: Can you provide the part of stack of the hanging thread from the client.execute(get) to the top (the apache code).

Answer (score 3):

I do not see anything obviously wrong with your code. I would strongly recommend setting SO_TIMEOUT parameter on the connection manager, though, to make sure it applies to all new socket at the creation time, not at the time of request execution.

I would also help to know what exactly 'freezing' means. Are worker threads getting blocked waiting to acquire connections from the pool or waiting for response data?

Please also note that worker threads can appear 'frozen' if the server keeps on sending bits of chunk coded data. As usual a wire / context log of the client session would help a lot
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/logging.html

Comment: I did specify a SocketTimeout in the RequestConfig that is used to build the CloseableHttpClient. Will this not apply to sockets at creation time?

Comment: No, it will not, if connection initialization involves an intermediate handshake such as TLS/SSL session setup or a connection tunnel setup with CONNECT method.